# Something like FindBugs for .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, findbugs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FindBugs for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397641/findbugs-for-net)

I need something like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) for C#/.NET ...

Could you tell me where I can find something like this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) is a static analysis tool for .NET that has the ability to detect various possible bugs as well as advise you of good programming practices and Microsoft naming conventions. It seems like Microsoft have stopped development on the standalone FxCop tool now in favour of encouraging you to buy a version of Visual Studio with the static code analysis built in (which I think for VS2010 is the "Premium" edition and above).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at FxCop. It's probably the most popular static code analysis tool for .NET.

Comment: You can use the SonarQube  static code analysis tool for analysing your source code without execting them and find potential  vulnerabilities, bug and security threats.